# Why is my label not displayed if it's set to visible

Tags: java, swing

I've tried to encapsulate my confusion in a minimal program. I know that when multiple components are added to, say, a JFrame's CENTER region, only the most recently added component is visible. But using getComponents() I can see that the earlier-added components are still "there." So I'm curious why I can't see the earlier-added component after I use setVisible(false) to hide the most recently added component? Thank you very much.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        jFrame.setSize( 300, 300 );
        jFrame.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

// 1. Put 2 JLabels in BorderLayout.CENTER
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel( "Label1" ), label2 = new JLabel( "Label2" );
        jFrame.add( label1, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        jFrame.add( label2, BorderLayout.CENTER );

// 2. Demonstrate that both JLabels are in the JFrame
        listAllComponents( jFrame ); // Show that jFrame contains both JLabels.

// 3. Hide the 2nd-added JLabel.
        label2.setVisible( false );
        label1.setVisible( true );  // WHY IS label1 NOT DISPLAYED?

// 4. Revalidate/repaint the JFrame
        jFrame.setVisible( true );
        jFrame.revalidate();
        jFrame.repaint();

// 5. Why isn't the 1st-added JLabel displayed?
    }

    // List all of a JFrame's JLabels' text strings (assumes JFrame only contains JLabels).
    static void listAllComponents( JFrame jFrame ) {
         Component[] components = jFrame.getContentPane().getComponents();
         System.out.println( "\nComponents in the JFrame:" );
         for ( Component component : components ) {
             System.out.printf( "\t%s\n", ((JLabel)component).getText() );
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: please improve the post title, it is unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that when multiple components are added to, say, a JFrame's CENTER region, only the most recently added component is visible. But using getComponents() I can see that the earlier-added components are still "there."

It is the job of the layout manager to set the size and location of the component.

When the frame is made visible, the layout manager is invoked and each component is given a size and location.

The `BorderLayout` only tracks the last component added for each constraint, so only the size/location for label2 is set.

The default size of a Swing component is (0, 0). Since that layout manager didn't change the size of label1, there is nothing to paint.

Try the following:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
    jFrame.setSize( 300, 300 );
    jFrame.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

    JLabel label1 = new JLabel( "Label1" );
    label1.setSize( label1.getPreferredSize() );
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel( "Label2" );
    jFrame.add( label1, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    jFrame.add( label2, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    jFrame.setVisible( true );
}
```

Now the first label has a size so it is painted at its default location even though the layout manager knows nothing about it.

If you really want two components to share the same space then you can use a `CardLayout`. The CardLayout WILL give a size/location to all components, but it will manage which component is visible and any given time.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working example.

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate your lucid explanation, and your suggestion to give the labels a size. I understand that there are other approaches that will provide the same effect (sharing a region); I was primarily interested in understanding *why* my code wasn't producing the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the component doesn't remove it. The `BorderLayout` still reference the last component. In fact, the `BorderLayout` doesn't know about the first component after the second one was added. The components in a `BorderLayout` do not "stack".
Check the fields in the [source code of `BorderLayout`](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/awt/BorderLayout-source.html):

```
/**
 * @serial
 */
private Component north;

/**
 * @serial
 */
private Component south;

[...]
```